# API not working in postman while testing it

Tags: java, postman, http-status-code-500

I'm Testing the API on Postman and the error while testing the API that I'm getting in the console is:

> 2023-09-29 17:14:53,673 68384308 [https-jsse-nio-8006-exec-8] ERROR c.w.e.service.EmailController - Error saving as draft for processinstanceid : DefaultInstanceID

I'm not able to find in the correct input for the below listed API for  `processinstanceid`. Below listed is the information about the code and the API .

The API is :- https://localhost:8006/app/Email/saveAsDraft,

More Information about the API :-

1. it is being used in a Post Method
2. the name of functionality is SaveAsDraft
3. the body necessary for the testing the API is in JSON format that i have picked from
   DataBase
4. the text in the JSON body of API in Postman is :-

   ```
             "messageId": "<5432112345@xyz.com>",
             "mailFrom": "kingissingh@xyz.com",
             "processinstanceid": "DefaultProcessID",
             "mailTo": "singhisking@xyz.com"
             "subject": "Hi im singh",
   ```

More Information about  Testing the API :-

1. While testing the API the response in postman is - Error while Saving as Draft
2. Not able to find the correct input for Body of "processinstanceid":
3. Internal Server Error 500.

[image: SCREENSHOT WHILE TESTING THE API]

Below listed is the code for the functionality of `SaveAsDraft` from which the API is being used :-

```
   @RequestMapping("/app/Email")
   @RestController
   public class EmailController {

   private Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmailController.class);

   @Autowired
   EmailService emailServices;

   
   @PostMapping(value = "/saveAsDraft")
   public ResponseEntity<Object> saveAsDraft(@RequestBody EmailConfiguration                                           
   emailConfiguration,HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {

            if (!emailServices.validateEmailConfiguration(emailConfiguration)) {
                return ResponseEntity.badRequest()
               .body(ApplicationConstants.INVALID_REQUEST);
                            }

             String currentStatus = "";
                try {
                 // Send the email using the GraphService
                 currentStatus = emailServices.saveAsDraft(emailConfiguration, httpRequest);

                 } catch (Exception e) {
                 log.error("Error saving as draft for processinstanceid : {}",          
         emailConfiguration.getProcessinstanceid());
                  return ResponseEntity.internalServerError()
                  .body(ApplicationConstants.ERROR_SAVING_DRAFT);
                    }
          return ResponseEntity.ok(currentStatus);
                     }
```

Below listed is the configuration format for SaveAsDraft API function

```
 @Override
  public boolean validateEmailConfiguration(EmailConfiguration config) {
        
        try {
            if(StringUtils.isBlank(config.getProcessinstanceid()) 
                    || StringUtils.isBlank(config.getSubject())
                    || StringUtils.isBlank(config.getMailFrom())
                    || StringUtils.isBlank(config.getMailTo())
                    ) {
                return false;
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {
            log.error("Validation of email configuration failed :{}, {}",e.getMessage(),e);
            return false;
        }
        
        return true;
}
```

Comment: A 500 error indicates that you're reaching the line starting with `return ResponseEntity.internalServerError() ...`.  You would get more clarity if you were to also log the exception itself, rather than just the `processinstanceid`.

Comment: Hi in the body of section of Postman , emailto , emailfrom , MessageID , subject , and processinstanceID needs to fetched in order for proper testing , Im not able to find what particular value of processinstanceID should be fed into body of API parameters as even while putting a dummy value i get the same error in console log     :-    2023-09-29 17:14:53,673 68384308 [https-jsse-nio-8006-exec-8] ERROR c.w.e.service.EmailController - Error saving as draft for processinstanceid : DefaultInstanceID

Comment: Do you have access to the server logs?  If so, try adding `log.error(e);` just above `return ResponseEntity.internalServerError()                  .body(ApplicationConstants.ERROR_SAVING_DRAFT);`.  Then you'll see if the exception itself provided you with any additional clues.

Comment: Hi , should remove the previously written log.error line and replace it with log.error(e);   the code will now look like this : -                                                                           } catch (Exception e) {
                 log.error(e);
                  return ResponseEntity.internalServerError()
                  .body(ApplicationConstants.ERROR_SAVING_DRAFT);

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Line breakpoint:EmailController [line: 46] - saveAsDraft(EmailConfiguration, HttpServletRequest)
 - The method error(String) in the type Logger is not applicable for the arguments (Exception)    , this is the error im getting in the code when im replacing log.error(e); which current log.error statement

Comment: the error in console while testing API of the first listed code is coming out to be :- "2023-10-01 19:22:16,174 102324 [https-jsse-nio-8006-exec-5] ERROR c.w.e.service.EmailController - Error saving as draft for processinstanceid : DefaultProcessID"

Comment: It looks like, from elsewhere in your code, that your Logger could handle this line instead:  `log.error("Error saving as draft for processinstanceid : {}, {}",          
         emailConfiguration.getProcessinstanceid(), e);`

Comment: Hi I , replaced the code with the statement you provided in place of my log statement , this is the error im getting in the console although its the same 2023-10-02 13:38:57,351 97987 [https-jsse-nio-8006-exec-5] ERROR c.w.e.service.EmailController - Error saving as draft for processinstanceid : DefaultProcessID_1, {}
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot determine target DataSource for lookup key [null]

Comment: Great.  So now you know you need to troubleshoot the connection to your SQL database.